# Why does the electron configuration for some elements not follow the diagonal rule?

Tags: electronic-configuration

I'm doing a high-school assignment, and I came across a question that I didn't quite understand.

> Explain how the electron configurations for the following elements do not follow the diagonal rule:
>
> - Gold
> - Curium
> - Thorium
> - Molybdenum
> - Palladium

From what I understand, all of these elements do follow the diagonal rule. How exactly do they not follow this rule?

Comment: Look them up—they're not what you think. For example, gold is [Xe] 4f14 5d10 6s1, not [Xe] 4f14 5d9 6s2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for these exceptions (from the diagonal rule) is that some elements are more stable with fewer electrons in some subshells and more electrons in others:

- Electronic configuration of molybdenum: $[\ce{Kr}] \ce{4d^{5} 5s^1}$, instead of  $[\ce{Kr}] \ce{5s^2 4d^{4}}$ according to the diagonal rule, because a half-full $\ce{4d}$ subshell and a half full $\ce{5s}$ subshell are more stable than $\ce{4d}$ filled with four electrons and a full $\ce{5s}$ subshell.
- Electronic configuration of Gold: $[\ce{Xe}] \ce{4f^14 5d^{10} 6s^1}$, instead of  $[\ce{Xe}] \ce{4f^14 5d^{9} 6s^2}$ according to the diagonal rule, because a full $\ce{5d}$ and half full $\ce{6s}$ subshell is more stable than $\ce{5d}$ filled with 9 electrons and a full $\ce{6s}$ subshell.
- Electronic configuration of Palladium: $[\ce{Kr}] \ce{4d^{10}}$, instead of  $[\ce{Kr}]\ce{ 5s^2 4d^{8}}$ according to the diagonal rule, because a full $\ce{4d}$ orbital is more stable than $\ce{4d}$ filled with eight electrons.
- Electronic configuration of Curium: $[\ce{Rn}] \ce{7s^2 5f^7 6d^{1}}$, instead of  $[\ce{Rn}] \ce{7s^2 5f^8} $ according to the diagonal rule, because a half full $\ce{5f}$ orbital is more stable than $\ce{5f}$ filled with eight electrons.